# Can any one explain me django blog code(Details inside)

Tags: django

I'm new to django. I'm reading blog [tutorial](http://www.lightbird.net/dbe/blog.html).From blog tutorial I'm unable to understand following part. Can any one explain me? I shall be very thankful.    thanks

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ["post"]

    def add_comment(request, pk):
        """Add a new comment."""
        p = request.POST

        if p.has_key("body") and p["body"]:
            author = "Anonymous"
            if p["author"]: author = p["author"]

            comment = Comment(post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk))
            cf = CommentForm(p, instance=comment)
            cf.fields["author"].required = False

            comment = cf.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = author
            comment.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dbe.blog.views.post", args=[pk]))
```

Comment: Is there a specific part you don't understand or would like to know more about?

Comment: @TomHarrigan  `if p.has_key("body") and p["body"]:
            author = "Anonymous"
            if p["author"]: author = p["author"]

            comment = Comment(post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk))
            cf = CommentForm(p, instance=comment)
            cf.fields["author"].required = False

            comment = cf.save(commit=False)`. I'm unable to understand this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ["post"]

    def add_comment(request, pk):
        """Add a new comment."""
        p = request.POST 

        # if POST has key "body" and p["body"] evalutes to True
        if p.has_key("body") and p["body"]: #


            author = "Anonymous"
            # if the value for key "author" in p evaluates to True
            # assign its value to the author variable.
            if p["author"]: author = p["author"]

            # create comment pointing to Post id: pk passed into this function
            comment = Comment(post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk))

            # generate modelform to edit comment created above
            cf = CommentForm(p, instance=comment)
            cf.fields["author"].required = False

            # use commit=False to return an unsaved comment instance
            # presumably to add in the author when one hasn't been specified.
            comment = cf.save(commit=False)
            comment.author = author
            comment.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dbe.blog.views.post", args=[pk]))
```

The author is trying to assign a default value to the author field if one isn't passed in.

You could probably shorten the code quite a bit by making a mutable copy of the `POST` `QueryDict` to solve the same problem.

Does this make more sense to you?

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        exclude = ["post"]

    def add_comment(request, pk):
        """Add a new comment."""
        p = request.POST.copy()

        if p.has_key("body") and p["body"]:
            if not p["author"]:
                p["author"] = 'Anonymous'

            comment = Comment(post=Post.objects.get(pk=pk))
            cf = CommentForm(p, instance=comment)
            cf.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dbe.blog.views.post", args=[pk]))
```

Comment: "if "author" in POST, assign var author to whatever was posted" is incorrect.

Comment: @Ignacio - good point! More like if the value for key author evaluates to true?

Comment: POST values are always strings, and there's only one value that can evaluate to false.

Comment: @Ignacio - Thanks again. You're right they are always strings... I removed the references to `None`. I'm just going to say the author is trying to supply a default value for author if it isn't filled out in the form.

Answer (score 0):

It checks if the user who is commenting using the form has filled the form ( author and body )
if the user has not entered the author name it will set it as Anonymous , and if both the fields (author and body) are empty, it will redirect back to the form ..